# np.hstack and np.vstack not run

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to combine three images.

```
img = cv2.imread('Lenna_(test_image).png', 0)
dim = (256, 256)
resizedLena = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

`Y` is an image modified by `img` and `X` is another image modified by `img` but equals to `img`

Now, I would like to combine `img, Y, X` with this command

```
newIMG = np.vstack((resizedLena, Y))
outputIMG = np.vstack((newIMG, X))
cv2.imshow('return IMG', outputIMG)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

1. 1° image is my output;
2. 2° image is `img`
3. 3° image is `Y`
4. 4° image is `X`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for anyone helping me

Comment: all images must be the same size

Comment: have all same size

Comment: it'swork for me, plz show all your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images of different sizes, you can combine them using `numpy`. Then you can create horizontal combines images.

You need to determine the indexes.

For instance:

- if the first image starts from `0:h1, 0:w1`
- Second image starts from `0:h1, w1:w1 + w2`
- Third image starts from `0:h1, w1 + w2:w1 + w2 + w3`
- Fourth image starts from `0:h1, w1 + w2 + w3:w1 + w2 + w3 + w4`

Result will be:

[image]

Code:

```py
from cv2 import imread, imshow, waitKey
from cv2 import IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, imwrite
from numpy import zeros

img1 = imread("1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = imread("2.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img3 = imread("3.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img4 = imread("4.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

(h1, w1) = img1.shape[:2]
(h2, w2) = img2.shape[:2]
(h3, w3) = img3.shape[:2]
(h4, w4) = img4.shape[:2]

out = zeros((h1, w1 + w2 + w3 + w4), dtype="uint8")

out[0:h1, 0:w1] = img1
out[0:h1, w1:w1 + w2] = img2
out[0:h1, w1 + w2:w1 + w2 + w3] = img3
out[0:h1, w1 + w2 + w3:w1 + w2 + w3 + w4] = img4

imwrite("out.png", out)

imshow("out", out)
waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The three best ways to do this using a single line of code. **However, the images to be concatenated must have the same dimensions and especially the same number of channels.**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np 


img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
dim = (256, 256)
resizedLena = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
X, Y = resizedLena, resizedLena

# Method 1: Using Numpy (hstack, vstack)
Fusion_Horizontal = np.hstack((resizedLena, Y, X))
Fusion_Vertical   = np.vstack((newIMG, X))

cv2.imshow('Fusion_Vertical using vstack', Fusion_Vertical)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Method 2: Using Numpy (contanate)
Fusion_Vertical   = np.concatenate((resizedLena, X, Y), axis=0)
Fusion_Horizontal = np.concatenate((resizedLena, X, Y), axis=1)

cv2.imshow("Fusion_Horizontal usung concatenate", Fusion_Horizontal)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# Method 3: Using OpenCV (vconcat, hconcat)
Fusion_Vertical   = cv2.vconcat([resizedLena, X, Y])
Fusion_Horizontal = cv2.hconcat([resizedLena, X, Y])

cv2.imshow("Fusion_Horizontal Using hconcat", Fusion_Horizontal)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Note:**
in case the images do not have the same dimensions, you must build an empty matrix and fill it yourself, as on the post just before.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could just put all three images in the parameter

```
newIMG = np.vstack((resizedLena, Y, X))
```